# UIImageView/UIView being stretched too tall

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiimageview

UPDATE:

```
estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath returns 500.0f



heightForRowAtIndexPath returns UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

I am trying to achieve self sizing table view cells, and i believe i correctly did autolayout.

For some reason, the UIImage or even the UIView thats the white part is being stretched really tall.

I have the `UIImageView`'s contentMode as `AspectFit`

No matter how i do autolayout, this problem still persists.

Grey background is the cell's contentView

White background is the UIView thats on top of contentView

UIImage is on top of the UIView.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont understand?

Comment: please asking a proper question

Comment: How is this not proper?

Comment: What are your autolayout settings?

Comment: @fabe where do i check the settings?

Comment: You wrote in the first sentence of your question: 'i believe i correctly did autolayout'. Have you used interface builder?

Comment: Which contraints do you want to see?

Comment: @fabe yes i used interface builder/storyboard

Comment: I have an assumption: The UIImageView has now a transparent background color. If you set something else you will see that the UIImageView fits to its superview. So your problem is that UIImageView does not fits to the UIImage. Am I right?

Comment: @fabe i added a IBOutlet for the imageview height constraint and set the height that way. But it seems to be laggy/glitchy this way. Only when i scroll, the correct layout is acheived

Answer (score 0):

check your Widths and heights are same as uiview and image view , and check height for row in table view

Comment: The question is about self sizing cells.

Comment: @fabe exactly, also to note, i have estimatedHeightForRow at about 500.0f
and heightForRowAtIndex is UITableViewAutomaticDimension